# Неверная цветопередача видео usb эндоскопа на raspberry pi debian

Tags: debian, камера, raspberry-pi

Привет. На распберри(дебиан ос) неверная цветопередача изображения с юсб камеры (эндоскопа). На компе под убунтой на том же проигрывателе mplayer все нормально.
Пробовал подкручивать контрастность, яркость - безрезультатно. Подключал также через шнур с доп питанием. 
В чем проблема? Если с драйверами, то как их перетянуть с убунты на дебиан?
Заранее спасибо)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

raspberry pi 2 b

```
lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1908:2311 GEMBIRD
dmesg
usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=1908, idProduct=2311
usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1.5: Product: USB2.0 PC Camera
usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Generic
uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 PC Camera (1908:2311)
input: USB2.0 PC Camera as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input2
usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
```

Comment: Модели, версии, напишите хотя бы ..

Comment: @kromster указал). обновления свежие.

Comment: Укажите также модель эндоскопа и его версию/прошивку, какие дравйвера вы поставили для него? А то пока видно только то, что это "USB2.0 PC Camera". Вцелом похоже на неправильно выбранный видеоформат - у вас есть возможность обновить драйвера или каким-то софтом повыбирать формат отдаваемой/показываемой картинки?

Comment: @kromster, android camera AN97. Другой информации нет.

Comment: Mplayer tv:// -tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video0

Comment: Помимо решения для mplayer, приведу настройку цветопередачи для ffmpeg. Настраивается через v4l2. Список параметров: v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 –L. Настройка параметров:
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl brightness=60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснилось, что mplayer просто сбрасывал настройки цветности.

Решение:

1. Ставим v4l2-ctl
2. Создаем файл v4l2.conf в /etc/mplayer/ со следующим содержимым:

> ```
> run "v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl brightness=60"
> run "v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl contrast=70"
> run "v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl saturation=30"
> run "v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl hue=0"
> run "v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl gamma=100"
> ```

Запускаем видеоплеер командой:

**mplayer tv:// -input file="/etc/mplayer/v4l2.conf" –tv driver=v4l2:device=/dev/video0**

Для разных камер скорее всего настройки будут разными.

**ADD**
настройку цветопередачи для ffmpeg.

Настраивается через v4l2.

Список параметров: v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 –L

Настройка параметров: v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-ctrl brightness=60